# Supply a different namespace for a DataMember in a WCF DataContract

Tags: xml, wcf, namespaces, wsdl

This is an example of a VB Class for one of my data data contracts:

```
<System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "2.0.50727.3038"), _
 System.SerializableAttribute(), _
 System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(), _
 System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code"), _
 System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute([Namespace]:="http://www.example.com/NS1"), _
 System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute([Namespace]:="http://www.example.com/NS1")> _
Partial Public Class SomeType
    ...
    Private someMemberField As String
    ... 

    <DataMember(Order:=4)> _
    Public Property SomeMember() As String
        Get
            Return Me.someMemberField
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            Me.someMemberField = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

WSDL becomes (namespace is http://www.example.com/NS1 as expected):

```
<xs:complexType name="SomeType">
  <xs:sequence>
    ...
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SomeMember" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    ...
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

A XML example is:

```
<SomeType xmlns="htttp://www.example.com/NS1">
   ...
   <SomeMember>some text</SomeMember>
   ...
</Sometype>
```

This is perfect to me. However my client (which is not WCF) needs a different namespace for the DataMember. A XML example like this:

```
<SomeType xmlns="http://www.example.com/NS1">
   ...
   <SomeMember xmlns="http://www.example.com/NS2">some text</SomeMember>
   ...
</Sometype>
```

I believe that the WSDL should look similar to this:

```
<xs:complexType name="SomeType">
  <xs:sequence>
    ...
    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SomeMember" nillable="true" type="xs:string" xmlns:q1="http://www.example.com/NS2"/>
    ...
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I know how to do it for complex data types.

All I have to do is change the namespace in the DataContractAttribute of the respective class, which I did for the members that aren't primitive data types.

Is this possible for primitive data types such as String?

I can't change namespaces in DataMembers and I can't figure out any other way of setting a different namespace for a primitive data type.

However, XML examples generated from XSD do include namespaces in primitive data type members.

Does anyone know how can I get something like this using WCF?

```
<SomeType xmlns="http://www.example.com/NS1">
   ...
   <SomeMember xmlns="http://www.example.com/NS2">some text</SomeMember>
   ...
</Sometype>
```

Thanks in advance,

Fernando Martins.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!

Using a service contract like this:

```
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="http://www.example.com/NS1")>
Public Interface MyServiceContract
    ... 
End Interface
```

XML for the class SomeType looks like this:

```
<SomeType xmlns="htttp://www.example.com/NS1">
   ...
   <SomeMember>some text</SomeMember>
   ...
</Sometype>
```

Adding the XmlSerializerFormat() to the service contract:

```
<ServiceContract(Namespace:="http://www.example.com/NS1")>
<XmlSerializerFormat()>
Public Interface MyServiceContract
    ... 
End Interface
```

XML becomes like this (namespaces are displayed for each member):

```
<SomeType>
   ...
   <SomeMember xmlns="htttp://www.example.com/NS1">some text</SomeMember>
   ...
</Sometype>
```

Then, the third-party client assigns for the SomeType the same namespace where SomeType is encapsulated.